# ActiveRecord::Relation#explain always runs the query in full

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, explain

I'm trying to use the explain method in both Rails 3 and 4 to estimate the number of rows returned in what can be a particularly expensive query.  It joins 3 tables and can result in table scans of 10 million row tables, which combined with the count() aggregate is particularly slow (database is Postgres 9.3).

My problem is this.  if I use the inbuilt explain() method, the query is always run IN FULL behind the scenes before returning a result.  This can take over 2 minutes.  There may be other scenarios where the query I want to analyse could take hours to run (eg for reports).

I have a slightly ugly solution where I do a to_sql, tack "explain" on the front, and execute the query.  This works in Rails 3 but required some rework for Rails 4.

So I suppose my question is this.  Is there a way to get the inbuilt AR explain() method to do what I want, is there some other elegant way to do this, or is this a bug in AR::explain() which needs to be logged and fixed at some point?

Comment: I can't believe rails does this (and can't be turned off with options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I did this.
In both Rails 3 and 4 I wrote an initializer for ActiveRecord::Relation.

First, in Rails 3:

```
class ActiveRecord::Relation
  HUGE_COUNT = 20000

  def count(column_name = nil, options = {})
    exact, has_conditions = false, false
    h = (column_name.class == Hash ? column_name : options)
    exact = h[:exact]
    has_conditions = h[:conditions]
    has_distinct = (column_name.class == String) && (column_name =~ /\bdistinct\b/i)
    h = h.except(:exact) # Remove it because super won't understand it
    column_name.class == Hash ? column_name = h : options = h
    if exact || has_conditions || has_distinct
      super
    else
      est = estimated_count
      est > HUGE_COUNT ? est : super
    end
  end

  def estimated_count
    node = connection.execute("EXPLAIN #{self.to_sql}").first
    match = node['QUERY PLAN'].match(/rows=\d+\b/)
    match ? match[0].split('=').last.to_i : 0
  end
```

end

Rails 4 is the same except for:

```
  def estimated_count
    node = {}
    connection.unprepared_statement do
      node = connection.execute("EXPLAIN #{self.to_sql}").first
    end
    match = node['QUERY PLAN'].match(/rows=\d+\b/)
    match ? match[0].split('=').last.to_i : 0
  end
```

HUGE_COUNT is low because so far I've found that this is generally very accurate to within 1 or 2%.  That is fine for my needs but obviously this is fairly dangerous ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a method that will do this asynchronously. However, you can definitely benefit by using **resque** or **sidekiq** to run your queries asynchronously.

Here's the link to resque:

https://github.com/resque/resque

Here's the link to sidekiq:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq

Comment: Thanks Rico but I really need to do this synchronously.  I worked out how to do this using to_sql so I'll write up my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's running the query in full is that ActiveRecord `.explain` is designed to run the query. It's not the same as a SQL `EXPLAIN`. It's more like a SQL `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

As the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#running-explain) suggests,

> explain actually executes the query, and then asks for the query plans.